# Installing MySQL in LAMP

Tags: installation, mysql, lamp

I managed to install Apache and PHP on my Ubuntu Installation, however when I try to install MySQL using this command

`sudo apt-get install mysql-server`

It mentions that there are broken packages. Any ideas on what I should have done, but haven´t possibly done?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

please give some more details. Which is your Ubuntu version? Which MySQL version do you want to install?

First advice: Do not install from the Ubuntu repos but download the latest MySQL version from dev.mysql.com. Choose the Generic Linux tarball for your OS platform (not the DEBs) and follow the step by step instructions on http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/binary-installation.html. Prior to the installation purge all parts of the package that might hang around.

Do not forget to provide a my.cnf configuration file in either /etc or /etc/mysql. In most cases the my-medium.cnf from the support-files directory is a good starting point.

If you have more questions feel free to come back.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about you guys but I prefer to install LAMP in a single line after reading about other methods.

This guide seemed to help as it had alot of screenshots: [Installing LAMP on Ubuntu](http://draalin.com/installing-lamp-on-ubuntu/). It has two different installation methods.